# ServiceStack.Razor breaks asp-net MVC app

Tags: servicestack

I have just created an asp.net MVC 4 application, and I have nugot the ServiceStack.Razor.
When I F5 the website, I get the following error

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or
>   one of its dependencies.

And a source error from web.config like this:

```
Line 27:     
Line 28:     <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"><assemblies>
Line 29:         <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
Line 30:       </assemblies><buildProviders>
Line 31:         <add extension=".cshtml" type="ServiceStack.Razor.CSharpRazorBuildProvider, ServiceStack.Razor" />
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use [ServiceStack.Razor](http://razor.servicestack.net/) together with MVC Razor which both have separate and conflicting Razor Code build providers. Either use normal (i.e. non-MVC) ASP.NET Web Application and add ServiceStack.Razor or if you use ASP.NET MVC you will only have access to MVC Razor.

Comment: Thought that ServiceStack.Razor was more like an addition to Razor. So it's not possible to use the SS.Razor with ASP.NET MVC at all?

Comment: Razor wasn't designed to be extensible, there can be only 1 Razor code build provider and when you have MVC, it (and VS.NET) expects to have full control over it. There is an opportunity to use SS.Razor with a different file extension (e.g. setting RazorFormat.RazorFileExtension), but I would recommend against the confusion of having 2 separate Razor engines within the same project, better to pick one or the other.

Comment: @mythz What do you suggest for an existing project that is slowly being converted entirely over to SS and SS Razor, but for the time being both have to coexist?